# How to create a shape animation with seamless textures

Tags: animation, texturing

Hi I'm trying to create an animation where shapes rise out of the floor and are seamlessly textured even though they move together.

However when placing my shapes side by side you can always see the join and i can't figure out a way to eliminate this. The below is what i'm trying to achieve: [image]

And this is an example of how the joins are clearly visible in my version so far:

[image]

I'm using cycles and can animate the shapes fine but they don't have the seamless look of the shapes in the ref. which actually grow out of the floor to form the staircase in the image.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: I think you should merge the vertices then apply the boolean. Can you elaborate a bit on your setup (base mesh ,animation, modifiers ?)

Comment: Hi, yeah sure thing. So the animation style is similar to what https://raggededge.com/ have on their home page. I'm really just trying to recreate something like this.

I'm currently using basic shapes so the default cube andcylinders and i've used a bevel modifier to soften them. The animation is just the shapes rising up as per the homepage video to form staircases or other forms. It's that seamless texture that makes them look like one shape that's almost covered by a single texture i can't work out. 

Thanks for trying to help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Alright, I can't say for sure how they achieve this effect, but what I'm almost certain is that the bevel operation should be the last thing you do to the mesh, otherwise you won't be able to remove the seam between your objects. I have a feeling they're using shader bevel and not geometry bevel though so that would help

Comment: Ok great i'll check out the bevel shader and see if i can create a similar effect. Thanks